# Cannot load the httparty gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, httparty

I am working on a rails model where I need to use the HTTParty gem. I am using bundler to manage my gems. Although I include HTTParty in the class of my Models directory, when I try to access it on my local server http://localhost:3000/, I get the following error:

```
uninitialized constant Recipe::HTTParty
```

I am using bundler so I have learnt that I do not need to require 'httparty'. But even when I do, I get:

```
cannot load such file -- httparty
```

After any change I make I restart my server. Would anyone know what I am doing wrong? I can't anything on google. Below you can see what error looks like when I do not require 'httparty'.

```
  class Recipe
    include HTTParty

    ENV['FOOD2FORK_KEY'] = 'e90655d68b4d4ccbc0c3125a5781da0f'
    hostport = ENV['FOOD2FORK_SERVER_AND_PORT'] || 'www.food2fork.com'
```

error trace:

```
Rails.root: /Users/Ilias/Documents/Rails Online Course Assignments/graded-assignments/Graded_Assignment_2/Assignment2/recipefinder

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/models/recipe.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
app/controllers/recipes_controller.rb:4:in `index'

This error occurred while loading the following files:
   httparty
```

my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0', '>= 5.0.0.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
# Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
# Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
gem 'web-console'
gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring'
gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Comment: I am using Ruby 2.2.3 and Rails 5.0.0.1

Comment: Would you please post your Gemfile?

Comment: @jvillian of course - I just edited my question to include the Gemfile.

Comment: There is no `httparty` gem in your Gemfile.

Comment: I don't see httparty anywhere...

Comment: Thanks guys - that was stupid. It was not in my slides that I have to specify the version in my Gemfile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you're missing `httparty` in your Gemfile. See 0:19 of the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OcPZDmdDQRg) you're following.

(Apologies for the earlier misfire and thank you go Зелёный for keeping me honest.)

Comment: Thank you jvillian.

Comment: Sure thing. Please feel free to accept if the mood strikes you. Good luck!